# How do I avoid `already defined` linking error with pugixml if two static libs contain pugixml objs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, pugixml

So I have 2 static libs defined like this:

**StaticLib1**

```
// StaticLib1.h
#pragma once

class StaticLib1
{
public:
  void doSomething1();
};
```

cpp:

```
// StaticLib1.cpp
#include "pugixml.hpp"
#include "StaticLib1.h"

void StaticLib1::doSomething1()
{
  pugi::xml_node node;
}
```

**StaticLib2**

```
// StaticLib2.h
#pragma once

class StaticLib2
{
public:
  void doSomething2();
};
```

cpp:

```
// StaticLib1.cpp
#include "pugixml.hpp"
#include "StaticLib2.h"

void StaticLib2::doSomething2()
{
  pugi::xml_node node;
}
```

**Main**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "StaticLib1.h"
#include "StaticLib2.h"

int main(int argv, char** argc)
{
  StaticLib1 staticlib1;
  StaticLib2 staticlib2;

  staticlib1.doSemething1();
  staticlib2.doSemething2();

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Now, if I build this. I get a lot of linking errors. Here are the first few linking errors:

```
3>StaticLib2.lib(StaticLib2.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall pugi::xml_attribute::xml_attribute(struct pugi::xml_attribute_struct *)" (??0xml_attribute@pugi@@QAE@PAUxml_attribute_struct@1@@Z) already defined in StaticLib1.lib(StaticLib1.obj)
3>StaticLib2.lib(StaticLib2.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall pugi::xml_attribute::xml_attribute(void)" (??0xml_attribute@pugi@@QAE@XZ) already defined in StaticLib1.lib(StaticLib1.obj)
3>StaticLib2.lib(StaticLib2.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall pugi::xml_attribute_iterator::xml_attribute_iterator(struct pugi::xml_attribute_struct *,struct pugi::xml_node_struct *)" (??0xml_attribute_iterator@pugi@@AAE@PAUxml_attribute_struct@1@PAUxml_node_struct@1@@Z) already defined in StaticLib1.lib(StaticLib1.obj)
...
...
```

Now, I understand that this linking error is because there is a `pugixml.obj` inside `StaticLib1.lib`, and there is `pugixml.obj` inside `StaticLib2.lib`. But I don't understand why this would cause  linking error with pugixml signatures. Why would they be defined twice? If I call `staticlib1.doSomething1()` shouldn't main not care if there are multiple definitions of `pugi`? Shouldn't `staticlib1.doSomething1()` handle all of that?

on the `pugiconfig.hpp` I have these specific settings:

```
#ifndef HEADER_PUGICONFIG_HPP
#define HEADER_PUGICONFIG_HPP

#define PUGIXML_WCHAR_MODE

#define PUGIXML_HEAD_ONLY
#include "pugixml.cpp"

#endif
```

Comment: _`#include "pugixml.cpp"`_ Is a very bad idea.

Comment: Okay so I commented that out. Now, I can't find references for `pugi::xml_node node` because there references for that are in `pugixml.objs`. Is it better then to make a static pugixml lib? so the refereces for `pugi::xml_node node` would be defined?

Comment: _"Is it better then to make a static pugixml lib?"_ Seems a better choice yes. Otherwise the order of the other libraries might also matter. You can put them into a linker object group also together with the `pugixml o` object file as well.

Answer (score 1):

So yes, from `user0042`advice, I realize it is better to compile a pugixml.lib on your own rather than having `#include "pugixml.cpp"` on the config. I'm working with legacy code so these surprises are there. Now, I've fixed my issue and made my company code slightly cleaner.

Comment: Note that the main reason why including pugixml.cpp didn't work for you is that the define is PUGIXML_HEADER_ONLY - you had a typo in the define so you were compiling pugixml in source mode.